# Nestjs ClientMqtt.emit publish both pattern and data to broker rather than only data

Tags: typescript, microservices, mqtt, nestjs, service-broker

I use Nestjs to publish data to a Mqtt Broker, but it sends the both pattern and data rather than only data like this:

```json
{
    "pattern": "test/test",
    "data": "Data"
}
```

In the `app.module.ts`, I import MQTT Client like this:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ClientsModule.register([
            {
                name: 'MQTT_CLIENT',
                transport: Transport.MQTT,
                options: {
                    url: 'tcp://abc.abc.com',
                    username: 'name',
                    password: 'psswrd',
                    port: 1883,
                },
            },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
```

and in `app.controller.ts`:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor(@Inject('MQTT_CLIENT') private client: ClientMqtt) {}

    async onApplicationBootstrap() {
        await this.client.connect();
    }

    @Get()
    getHello(): string {
        this.client.emit('test/test', 'Data')
        return 'Done';
    }
}
```

I also found that in the `ClientMqtt` proxy [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/f472852d441b7f66e52449e09f885ab57807bf96/packages/microservices/client/client-mqtt.ts#L127), method `publish` is to publish all the `partialPacket` which is the JSON {pattern, data} rather than only `packet.data`

```js
protected publish(
    partialPacket: ReadPacket,
    callback: (packet: WritePacket) => any,
  ): Function {
    try {
      const packet = this.assignPacketId(partialPacket);
      const pattern = this.normalizePattern(partialPacket.pattern);

      ...
        this.mqttClient.publish(
          this.getAckPatternName(pattern),
          JSON.stringify(packet),
        );
      });
      ...
  }
```

So if I just want to use `ClientMqtt` proxy but just only publish the data field of the packet, how can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the structure of the message sent to the MQTT broker using the serializers. For doing this you need include the 'serializer' attribute in the ClientsModule registration:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ClientsModule.register([
            {
                name: 'MQTT_CLIENT',
                transport: Transport.MQTT,
                options: {
                    url: 'tcp://abc.abc.com',
                    username: 'name',
                    password: 'psswrd',
                    port: 1883,
                    serializer: new OutboundResponseSerializer()
                },
            },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
```

With this change you need to create the 'OutboundResponseSerializer' class in other file that implements the method 'serialize':

```
import { Serializer, OutgoingResponse } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export class OutboundResponseSerializer implements Serializer {

    private readonly logger = new Logger('OutboundResponseIdentitySerializer');

    serialize(value: any): OutgoingResponse {
      this.logger.debug(`-->> Serializing outbound response: \n${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
      return value.data;
    }
}
```

With this changes, your messages only contains the data information.

You can find more information about this in the section 'Implementing Serializers and Deserializers' in this link: https://dev.to/nestjs/integrate-nestjs-with-external-services-using-microservice-transporters-part-3-4m20

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and I used it nest-mqtt

Comment: More details perhaps? How would that address the issue?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [nest-mqtt](https://github.com/microud/nest-mqtt#readme)

Answer (score 0):

> app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MqttModule } from 'nest-mqtt';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MqttModule.forRoot({
      host: '192.168.0.73',
      port: 1883,
      clientId: 'clientId',
      username: 'your username',
      password: 'your password',
      clean: false ,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> app.service.ts

```
/**nest-mqtt */
import { MqttService, Payload, Subscribe } from 'nest-mqtt';


/**nestjs common */
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MqttService) private readonly mqttService: MqttService,
  ) {}


  /**Subscription information */
  @Subscribe('your subject')
  async handleGetDeviceData(@Payload() payload: ISubjectSendData) {
   // Processing received messages
  }

  /**publish payload */
  async handelSendMsgToDevice(device: string, payload: any) {
    this.mqttService.publish(device, payload);
  }

}
```